# Updating a Django Entry in Test

Tags: django, http, tdd

Following up from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188822/django-forbidden-httpresponse-in-test-drive), I'm attempting to, with TDD, make a post, and verify that the post model can be edited in Admin, using only the same test.

The error indicates the update is not taking place:

```
self.assertEqual(testPost.title, 'New Title')

AssertionError: 'Title' != 'New Title'
- Title
+ New Title
? ++++
```

Here's the test giving the error:

```
    def testEditPost(self):
        self.client.login(username='user',password='password')
        response = self.client.post('/admin/blog/post/add/', {
            'title': 'Title',
            'text': 'Body',
        }, follow=True)

        allPosts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(allPosts), 1)

        response = self.client.patch('/admin/blog/post/1/', {
            'title': 'New Title',
            'text': 'New Body',
        }, follow=True)

        allPosts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(allPosts), 1)
        testPost = allPosts[0]
        self.assertEqual(testPost.title, 'New Title')
```

As you can see, it makes it up until the last line. 
I've tried adjusting the HTTP verb the client is using, but whether it's post, put, or patch, makes no difference.

Comment: Before anything, you need to be sure `1` is the pk of the first post, could you please check this inside the test? try to `print allPosts[0].pk` Also, it could be great if you add the code of your view as well.

Comment: Thanks, @trinchet. 
So, I did a fix to prevent that error, as follows:
`response = self.client.post('/admin/blog/post/%d/' % allPosts[0].pk`, to guarantee I'm heading to the right url.

However, this has not fixed the issue.
Currently, this isn't actually for a view, I'm merely testing on Admin, hence the login. So, I guess the view is the standard admin page.